# What should go in a PDFTron custom script?

Tags: javascript, pdfnet, pdftron

PDFTron has the option to provide a custom Javascript file to modify the viewer, but I'm not sure what should go in this file, and I can't find any examples on the web.

The website has the following description:

> Viewer Options - By default, PWS Cloud documents are loaded in a basic hosted version of WebViewer. You can customize the viewer's appearance, branding and custom features by loading an external JavaScript configuration file.

When I supply this file, **window.WebViewerUniversalInstance** is null, and **document.getElementById('DocumentViewer')** returns a null object also.

Can somebody point me in the right direction here, I'm lost.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This JavaScript file is run in the context of the viewer's inner html page (ReaderControl.html) allowing you to modify things directly in the viewer so WebViewerUniversalInstance will be null (as that's not in the inner page). However I made a small test file with `var ele = document.getElementById('DocumentViewer');` and ele wasn't null so I'm not quite sure why that wasn't working for you.

Anyway, some examples of things you can do. For custom actions you'll probably want to run your code in the "viewerLoaded" or "documentLoaded" events. For UI changes you shouldn't need to have code in either event.

So for example if you wanted to hide the print button you could just put in your file:

```
$('#printButton').hide();
```

For modifying UI related things I would recommend right-click, Inspect Element to find the ids/classes of things you want to modify. Alternatively you can download [WebViewer](https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/download.html) and take a look at ReaderControl.html.

Here's an example of doing something in the viewerLoaded event:

```
$(document).on('viewerLoaded', function() {
    readerControl.docViewer.SetMargin(0);
});
```

And here's an example of doing something in the documentLoaded event:

```
$(document).on('documentLoaded', function() {
    readerControl.setCurrentPageNumber(2);
    readerControl.rotateClockwise();
    readerControl.setZoomLevel(2);
});
```

There are many, many more things you could do and you can view the documentation here: http://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/demo/lib/html5/doc/

Some objects you might be interested in:

- readerControl: available after viewerLoaded
- [DocumentViewer](http://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/demo/lib/html5/doc/symbols/CoreControls.DocumentViewer.html): available after viewerloaded (readerControl.docViewer)
- [Document](http://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/demo/lib/html5/doc/symbols/CoreControls.Document.html): available after documentLoaded (docViewer.GetDocument())

If you have more questions you can always ask on the WebViewer forums: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pdfnet-webviewer

Comment: Do you know if there's any way I can provide a value to the viewer if hosting on Pdftron? We are trying to open the viewer with a search already completed. Doing the search part is fine, and have gotten to grips with how to work with the viewer generally with Javascript, but providing a value from our website to the viewer is a pain, because of cross domain request blocking etc. Would there any way we could provide a value to the viewer, perhaps as a parameter on the URL?

Comment: Can you enable CORS on your server for the request you're doing (http://enable-cors.org/server.html)? I just did a little test where I enabled it on my server and then did something simple like $.get("myserver.com/test.php", function(result) {...}). Then in the callback I started the search and that all seemed to work.

Comment: Hi @mparizeau have you considered exposing some of the more common functionality such as search via a URL. This would avoid the need for consumers to even consider CORS. Would be really helpful.

Comment: I forgot that you actually should be able to get the query parameters of the parent page from your config file by looking at window.parent.location.search and parsing that. Then you could pass any information you want through the URL.

Comment: @mparizeau The main problem here is that we are redirected away from the original URL provided to us via PdfTron to a second one, so any extra parameters we provide to URL A get lost once we arrive at URL B. We need to pass a single value the whole way through, I guess this is essentially a feature request, is there any way a parameter could be added to the URL provided that would be passed through to the destination URL?

Comment: You're right, I overlooked the redirect! We will consider adding something like this (custom query parameters), however I think I have a workaround that will work for now. If you add the query parameter ?redirect=false to the end of your URL then an XML response will be returned that includes the full URL that will be redirected to. Once you have the full URL you'll be able to add any extra query parameters that you want.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure i completely understood your questions, but here is what i did for external config file in PDFViewer, hope this will help to some extent:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var customData = { serviceUrl: 'services/PDFWebService.asmx', token: '<%=initialDoc.Value %>', isReadonly: '<%=IsReadonly?"yes":"no" %>' };
    var myWebViewer = new PDFTron.WebViewer({
        path: "Resources/js/PDFTron",
        mobileRedirect: false, // Disable redirect in mobile view.
        stream: true,
        config: 'Resources/js/PDFViewerConfig.js',
        documentType: "pdf",
        custom: JSON.stringify(customData),
        l: '<%=LicenseKey%>',
        initialDoc: customData.serviceUrl + '/GetFile?token=' + customData.token
    }, document.getElementById('viewer'));
});
```

My PDFViewerConfig.js is :

```
(function () {

$(document).on('viewerLoaded', function () {
    customData = JSON.parse(window.ControlUtils.getCustomData());
    SetupCustomizations();
});

$(document).on('documentLoaded', function () {
    setDisabled("#btnSave");
    setDisabled("#btnReset");
    setDisabled("#btnPushUp");
});

$(document).on('pageChanged', function (event) {

    var currentPageNumber = readerControl.getCurrentPageNumber();
    var totalPages = readerControl.docViewer.getDocument().getPageCount();
    if (currentPageNumber == totalPages) {
        setDisabled("#btnPushDown");
        setEnabled("#btnPushUp");
    }
    else if (currentPageNumber == 1) {
        setDisabled("#btnPushUp");
        setEnabled("#btnPushDown");
    }
    else {
        setEnabled("#btnPushUp");
        setEnabled("#btnPushDown");
    }
});
})();

function SetupCustomizations() {

if (customData && customData.isReadonly != "yes") {
    var removeButton = $('<span aria-disabled="false" role="button" tabindex="0" class="glyphicons  remove" title="remove page"></span>');
    var saveButton = $('<span aria-disabled="true" role="button" tabindex="0" id="btnSave" class="glyphicons floppy_disk disabled" title="save changes"></span>');
    var resetButton = $('<span aria-disabled="true" role="button" tabindex="0" id="btnReset" class="glyphicons restart disabled" title="reset to original"></span>');

    var rotateRightButton = $('<span aria-disabled="false" role="button" tabindex="0" class="glyphicons share" title="rotate right"></span>');
    var rotateLeftButton = $('<span aria-disabled="false" role="button" tabindex="0" class="glyphicons unshare" title="rotate left"></span>');

    var pushDownButton = $('<span aria-disabled="false" role="button" tabindex="0" id="btnPushDown" class="glyphicons down_arrow" title="move current page down"></span>');
    var pushUpButton = $('<span aria-disabled="true" role="button" tabindex="0" id="btnPushUp" class="glyphicons up_arrow disabled" title="move current page up"></span>');


    removeButton.on('click', onRemove);
    removeButton.on('keydown', onRemove);

    saveButton.on('click', onSave);
    saveButton.on('keydown', onSave);

    resetButton.on('click', onReset);
    resetButton.on('keydown', onReset);

    rotateRightButton.on('click', onRotateRight);
    rotateRightButton.on('keydown', onRotateRight);

    rotateLeftButton.on('click', onRotateLeft);
    rotateLeftButton.on('keydown', onRotateLeft);

    pushDownButton.on('click', onPushDown);
    pushDownButton.on('keydown', onPushDown);

    pushUpButton.on('click', onPushUp);
    pushUpButton.on('keydown', onPushUp);

    var newButtonsPlaceholder = $("#downloadButton").parent();
    newButtonsPlaceholder.prepend(removeButton);
    newButtonsPlaceholder.prepend(rotateLeftButton);
    newButtonsPlaceholder.prepend(rotateRightButton);
    newButtonsPlaceholder.prepend(pushDownButton);
    newButtonsPlaceholder.prepend(pushUpButton);
    newButtonsPlaceholder.prepend(saveButton);
    newButtonsPlaceholder.prepend(resetButton);
}

//508
$("#ui-id-3").attr("tabindex", "0");
$("#prevPage").attr("tabindex", "0");
$("#nextPage").attr("tabindex", "0");
$("#printButton").attr("tabindex", "0");
$("#fullScreenButton").attr("tabindex", "0");
$("#downloadButton").attr("tabindex", "0");
$("#zoomIn").attr("tabindex", "0");
$("#zoomOut").attr("tabindex", "0");
$("#fitWidth").attr("tabindex", "0");
$("#fitPage").attr("tabindex", "0");

$("#prevPage").attr("role", "button");
$("#nextPage").attr("role", "button");
$("#printButton").attr("role", "button");
$("#fullScreenButton").attr("role", "button");

$("#zoomIn").attr("role", "button");
$("#zoomOut").attr("role", "button");
removeExtraButtons();
}
```